# How to Revert a TypeList back to its original parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble finding information on how to use c++11 variadic TypeLists as containers for portable parameter packs. Lets say I had this piece of code.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, U, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + Index<T, Ts...>::value> {};
```

I can use it to find the first index of a type inside of a parameter pack like this.

```
int main() 
{
using namespace std;

cout << Index<int, int>::value << endl;                //Prints 0
cout << Index<char, float, char>::value << endl;       //Prints 1
cout << Index<int, double, char, int>::value << endl;  //Prints 2
}
```

How could I achieve this behavior for a TypeList? I'm trying to create something like this.

```
template <typename ...>
struct TypeList {};

int main() 
{
using namespace std;
using List = TypeList<char, short, long>

cout << Index<short, ConvertToParameterPack<List>::types...>::value << endl;  //Prints 1
}
```

Where ConvertToParameterPack is some method of reverting a TypeList back to its ParameterPack. If what I'm asking is impossible, are there any other good ways to solve this?

Comment: That syntax is impossible, but the problem can be solved many ways.  Like writing an expander that takes a template and a list and expands the list into the template.  Missing details, like can you redefine `Index`, or is this just about `Index` or `Index` is just an example, matter to what the best answer is.

Comment: Index was just an example. I'd also like to Convert a TypeList into Parameter Packs for other functions or to construct a tuple from a TypeList. I'm fine with refactoring code like Index to suite the needs for a TypeList approach, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t,I>;

template<class T, class List>
struct Index{}; 

template<class T, class...Ts>
struct Index<T, TypeList<T,Ts...>>:
  index_t<0>
{};

template<class T,class U, class...Ts>
struct Index<T, TypeList<U,Ts...>>:
  index_t< 1+Index<T,TypeList<Ts...>::value >
{}
```

Comment: So a good approach to this would be overloading the methods for the type list?