# How do I rebuild parameter pack from TypeList

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a variadic template typelist:

```
template <class... Types>
struct typelist {};
```

Then how can I pass it to some external code that expects a parameter pack, say `std::tuple`. In other word, I need to store the parameter pack as a member or typedef in my typelist, like

```
...
struct typelist {
    using types = Types; // Imaginary syntax
}
```

Yet this is rejected by the compiler saying Types is unexpanded.

Any workaround?

*This question is mentioned in another way in [comments of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097153/how-to-revert-a-typelist-back-to-its-original-parameter-pack), yet was not covered by the existing answer.*

---

Details as requested in comments:

If I compile (-std=c++17):

```
template <class... T>
struct typelist {};

std::tuple<typelist<int, int>> tp{0,1};
```

g++ gives `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tuple<typelist<int, int> >::tuple(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 std::tuple<typelist<int, int>> tp{0,1};`

If I compile (-std=c++17):

```
template <class... T>
struct typelist {
    using types = T;
};
```

`g++` gives `error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
     using types = T;`

Comment: Please attach the exact error message.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, please see the modified version.

Comment: once you have a `typelist`, just specialize/overload on that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a bit of boilerplate to get the right `tuple` specialization out of a `typelist`, for you can't simply store the parameter pack as it is.
As an example, you could do that by using properly a function declaration and an using declaration:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template <class... T>
struct typelist {};

template<typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> foo(typelist<T...>);

template<typename L>
using tupleFromTypelist = decltype(foo(std::declval<L>()));

int main() {
    using tl = typelist<int, int>;
    tupleFromTypelist<tl> tp{0,1};
    static_assert(std::is_same<tupleFromTypelist<tl>, std::tuple<int, int>>::value, "!");
}
```

Or an helper class like the one in the following example:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template <class... T>
struct typelist {};

template<typename>
struct helper;

template<typename... T>
struct helper<typelist<T...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<T...>;
};

int main() {
    using tl = typelist<int, int>;
    helper<tl>::type tp{0,1};
    static_assert(std::is_same<helper<tl>::type, std::tuple<int, int>>::value, "!");
}
```

Otherwise, let `typelist` expose the `tuple` specialization and get it directly from it:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template <class... T>
struct typelist {
    using tuple = std::tuple<T...>;
};

int main() {
    using tl = typelist<int, int>;
    tl::tuple tp{0,1};
    static_assert(std::is_same<tl::tuple, std::tuple<int, int>>::value, "!");
}
```

If it's the only type for which you want to use the parameter pack, this is the easiest approach.

Comment: Finally I used a helper class for this instead of function, thanks.

Comment: @YiFei Added an example with an helper class to the answer for completeness.

Comment: I had a template template class defining `type` instead, like those in type_traits. Anyway all the methods mentioned will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't store a parameter pack in a type alias. You need to use template argument deduction to extract the arguments of your `type_list` for reuse. One way is to use a dummy function like so:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct type_list {};

template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> to_tuple(type_list<Args...>);

template <typename TypeList>
struct type_list_to_tuple {
  using type = decltype(to_tuple(std::declval<TypeList>()));
};

template <typename TypeList>
using type_list_to_tuple_t = typename type_list_to_tuple<TypeList>::type;

int main() {
  using my_type_list = type_list<int, float>;
  using my_tuple = type_list_to_tuple_t<my_type_list>;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_tuple, std::tuple<int, float>>);
}
```